# relative sizing of subforms in ms access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

How do you set heights and widths of subforms to be percent of available screen real estate in ms access 2010?  In particular, I have a nested navigation subform labeled "Tab A" in the database that I uploaded to this file sharing url:  http://jmp.sh/v/HGctZ4Ru74vDAjzN43Wq

In the database at the file sharing link, different users with different screen resolution settings have the navigation subform with Tab A showing up in all different sizes, including some where the subform is a ridiculously small percentage of the available screen real estate.  The height of the detail section of the navigation subform is set to 5.5542 inches.  Is there some way to set it so that the height is 90% of the space available below the top of the subform?  I would also like for the width of the subform labeled "Tab 1" to be 90% of what is to the right of the left edge.  In java, this is easy with offsets and calculated widths.  I just cant seem to find instructions for how to do relative dimensions in access 2010.

Google searches on the topic don't seem to produce any solutions, and I want to avoid screwing up all the other users' screens by just adding an inch or two to the height setting.

Comment: I hate it when you click a link and it says _The file you are looking for does not exist. It may have been removed._

Answer (score 6):

In Access forms, all percentages or relative sizes are going to have to be calculated by you. I admit that sizing of forms and elements in Access is a little rigid and clumsy, but that's true of many desktop application GUI environments. I think .NET WPF has tried to fix this problem, but that has nothing to do with MS Access.

I usually end up using something like this. This code belongs on the main form. That's where I always do my resizing.

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.subform1.Width = Me.WindowWidth - 390
    'or if you want to account for the form's left property
    'Me.subform1.Width = Me.WindowWidth - (Me.subform1.Left + 100)
End Sub
```

**Edit1:**

In answer to your comment, 390 and 100 are twips. While design-time in Access does using inches, runtime properties must be set using twips.

I messed with this for a bit and couldn't get anything I considered to be perfectly accurate. I'm posting the code below that makes the most logical sense to me, but then I don't know the ins and outs of how forms sizes are calculated in MS Access. It seems I'm probably missing something because the code below does not product accurate results. I found by increasing my Margins and decreasing the percentage/decimal for subform's height calculation I was able to get something that appeared relatively close but was unsatisfactory if you demand precise and exact numbers.

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()
    On Error Resume Next
    Const RMARGIN = 0
    Const BMARGIN = 0
    Me.subform1.Left = Round(Me.WindowWidth * 0.1) - RMARGIN
    Me.subform1.Top = Round(Me.WindowHeight * 0.1) - BMARGIN
    Me.subform1.Width = Round(Me.WindowWidth * 0.9) - (Me.subform1.Left + RMARGIN)
    Me.subform1.Height = Round(Me.WindowHeight * 0.9) - (Me.subform1.Top + BMARGIN)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  This helps.  But why are you using numbers like 390 and 100? I thought access dimensions were in inches.  Also, are you able to show an example of a Form_Resize() method that places the subform in the center of the form with 10% offsets on all four sides?